# How to work with accelerometer data from the Apple Watch?

Tags: ios, swift, core-motion

Via the code below I am getting accelerometer data, now I want to work with it to track the user's movement, specifically speed. Looking around at code using Core Motion on the iPhone they are using a `motionManager` object which can set a value for `accelerometerUpdateInterval` as well as get the `.acceleration.x` value for example.   How can I work with the raw data I'm given back so that I can determine e.g. how fast a person is moving or how fast their arm is swinging?

```
//Record the data
if CMSensorRecorder.isAccelerometerRecordingAvailable() {
            print("Accelerometer available")
            recorder.recordAccelerometer(forDuration: 20 * 60)  // Record for 20 minutes
        }
  //Read the data
  if CMSensorRecorder.isAccelerometerRecordingAvailable() {
                let accelerometerData = recorder.accelerometerData(from: startDate, to: endDate)
                for (index, data) in (accelerometerData?.enumerated())! {
                    print(index, data)

                }
            }

Prints: 

0 388, 208409.082611, 529770182.607276, (0.038574, -0.762207, -0.652832)
1 388, 208409.102722, 529770182.627387, (0.027588, -0.763184, -0.660889)
2 388, 208409.122863, 529770182.647528, (0.027100, -0.763184, -0.661865)
3 388, 208409.142974, 529770182.667639, (0.030029, -0.756836, -0.661865)
4 388, 208409.163116, 529770182.687781, (0.026611, -0.764648, -0.665039)
```

Edit:  I found this lib which looks like it would be perfect but hasn't been updated in 3 years...anything similar that is still maintained?  https://github.com/MHaroonBaig/MotionKit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that using a `CMMotionManager` on the watch works just as good as it does on iPhone.  This way you can implement `startAccelerometerUpdates` in `awake` and receive real time feed back on watch positions for X Y Z coordinates so that you can get a better grasp of the data;

```
var motionManager = CMMotionManager() 

override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
        super.awake(withContext: context)

        manager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.2

        manager.startAccelerometerUpdates(to: OperationQueue.current!) { (data, error) in
            if let myData = data {

                 print("x: \(myData.acceleration.x) y: \(myData.acceleration.y) z: \(myData.acceleration.z)")
                if myData.acceleration.x > 1.5 && myData.acceleration.y > 1.5 {

                }
            }
        }



    }
```